# Counting the number of a specific string in another string

Tags: python, string, substring

Given a string s, with length N, contain those letters: R G B
count the number of triples (i, j, k) (1 <= i < j< k<= N)
Si != Sj != Sk; j - i != k - j
first line contains N, next line contains s

```
N = int(input())
s = input()
res = s[1:]
cnt = 0
for i in range(len(res)):
    if res[i-1] == 'R':
        for k in range(len(res)-1):
            if res[k] == "G":
                for t in range(len(res)-2):
                    if res[t+1] == "B":
                        cnt += 1
print(cnt)
```

```
example input
4
RRGB

output
1

I expected its outcome would be 1, but instead it returns 0
```

Comment: Why not like `print(s.count("RGB"))` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
# You only need one loop

N = int(input())
s = input()
cnt = 0
for i in range(1,len(s)-1):
    if s[i-1] == "R" and s[i] == "G" and s[i+1] == "B":
        cnt+=1
print(cnt)
```

Comment: well there could also be an input like this RGBGGRBGGBRGB

Comment: @yeet can you edit your question to be a bit clearer?